# What version of hadoop to install and run?

Tags: hadoop

After reading this article...

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/01/an-update-on-apache-hadoop-1-0/

If I were to make a brand new installation of hadoop to work with... is it still 0.23 today that has all the features? Or is there a better version that is out there now that has everything and captures all features and performance? There are so many guides out there that use 0.20... makes it seem as if 1.0 is not to be trusted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a guide I have followed at least three times to install and run on single node and two-node clusters and Michael does a pretty good job of keeping it current:

[Running Hadoop on Ubuntu Linux (Single-Node Cluster)](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)

[Running Hadoop on Ubuntu Linux (Multi-Node Cluster)](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/)

This uses version Hadoop version 1.0.3 released in May 2012; The latest stable as of this writing is 1.1.2, but if you want to do a first install to test and become familiar a guide like the one above may help you familiarize with the system and then upgrade to the latest-one once you have a reference point.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Hadoop [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html#Download) for the status of the different releases. As of now 1.0.4 is the stable release.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this tutorial for setting up a single node cluster in ubuntu 12.04. 
http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/hadoop_installation.php. I followed the tutorial and i successfully installed hadoop 1.1.2 on my linux system.